# Como ordeno las salidas de un método (Ascendente y descendente) en Java (Simulador de carrera)

Tags: java

1.Tengo una competencia, en donde se trata de simular una carrera, los tiempos y los competidores,
se generan de forma aleatoria, existen 5 competencias y cada competidor debe de competir en las
5 competencias las cuales van por edad y equipos.

```
    package capalogica;

import java.util.Arrays;

import java.util.HashSet;

import java.util.Set;

public class competencias {

    private CincoCompetencias[] arregloArticulos;
    private final int ETAPAS = 5;
    private final int COMPETIDORES = 10;
    private competidores[][] etapas = new competidores[ETAPAS][COMPETIDORES];
    private competidores[] GuardaCompetidores = new competidores[COMPETIDORES];
    private competidores objCompetidores = new competidores();

    public competencias() {

    }

    public void generarCompetencias() {
        int vueltas = (int) (Math.random() * 31) + 20;
        double pulgadas = 8150 * vueltas;
        double kilometraje = 0.20701 * pulgadas;

    }

    
    public void generaCompetidores() {

        int Busqueda = 0;
        int cedula = 0;
        int edad = 0;
        String categoria = "";
        String equipo = "";
        boolean encontro;
        int tamanno = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < COMPETIDORES; i++) {
            competidores objCompetidores = new competidores();
            cedula = (int) (Math.random() * 401) + 100;
            edad = (int) (Math.random() * 63) + 18;
            if (edad >= 18 && edad <= 25) {
                categoria = "Juvenil";
            } else {
                if (edad >= 26 && edad <= 35) {
                    categoria = "Adulto";
                } else {
                    if (edad >= 36 && edad <= 45) {
                        categoria = "Adulto Mayor";
                    } else {
                        if (edad >= 46 && edad <= 55) {
                            categoria = "Veterano";
                        } else {
                            categoria = "Oro";
                        }
                    }
                }
                encontro = false;
                for (Busqueda = 0; Busqueda < i; Busqueda++) {
                    if (GuardaCompetidores[Busqueda].getCedula() == cedula) {
                        encontro = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (edad >= 18 && edad <= 20) {
                equipo = " Rápidos y Furiosos";
            } else {
                if (edad >= 21 && edad <= 30) {
                    equipo = "Velocidad Total";
                } else {
                    if (edad >= 31 && edad <= 50) {
                        equipo = " Prudencia";
                    } else {
                        equipo = "Prudencia Total";
                    }
                }

            }
            objCompetidores.setCedula(cedula);
            objCompetidores.setEdad(edad);
            objCompetidores.setCategoria(categoria);
            objCompetidores.setEquipo(equipo);
            GuardaCompetidores[i] = objCompetidores;
            GuardaCompetidores[i].infoCompetidores();
            etapas[tamanno][i] = objCompetidores;

        }
    }

    public String imprimeCompetidores() {
        String hilera = "";
        int tamanno = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < COMPETIDORES; i++) {
            objCompetidores = etapas[tamanno][i];
            hilera += objCompetidores.infoCompetidores();
        }
        return hilera;
    }

    public void competirMangos() {
        int tiempo;
        for (int i = 0; i < COMPETIDORES; i++) {

            objCompetidores = etapas[0][i];
            tiempo = (int) (Math.random() * 30000) + 2000;
            objCompetidores.setTiempoMangos(tiempo);
            etapas[1][i] = objCompetidores;
            GuardaCompetidores[i] = objCompetidores;
        }
        this.Ordenar();
    }

    public void competirHato() {
        int tiempo;
        int tamanno = 0;
        int tamannoCompetidores = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < COMPETIDORES; i++) {

            objCompetidores = etapas[tamannoCompetidores][i];
            tiempo = (int) (Math.random() * 30000) + 10000;

            objCompetidores.setTiempoHato(tiempo);
            etapas[tamanno][i] = objCompetidores;

        }
        this.Ordenar();
    }

    public void competirChuchecas() {
        int tamanno = 1;
        int tamannoCompetidores = 0;
        int tiempo;
        for (int i = 0; i < COMPETIDORES; i++) {

            objCompetidores = etapas[tamannoCompetidores][i];
            tiempo = (int) (Math.random() * 30000) + 5000;

            objCompetidores.setTiempoChuchecas(tiempo);
            etapas[tamanno][i] = objCompetidores;

        }
        this.Ordenar();
    }

    public void competirGanaderos() {
        int tamanno = 1;
        int tamannoCompetidores = 0;
        int tiempo;
        for (int i = 0; i < COMPETIDORES; i++) {

            objCompetidores = etapas[0][i];
            tiempo = (int) (Math.random() * 30000) + 30000;

            objCompetidores.setTiempoGanaderos(tiempo);
            etapas[2][i] = objCompetidores;

        }
        this.Ordenar();
    }

    public void competirPampa() {
        int tiempo;
        for (int i = 0; i < COMPETIDORES; i++) {

            objCompetidores = etapas[0][i];
            tiempo = (int) (Math.random() * 30000) + 30000;

            objCompetidores.setTiempoPampa(tiempo);
            etapas[1][i] = objCompetidores;

        }
        this.Ordenar();
    }

    public int sumaTiemposEquipoRapidos() {
        int tiempo = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < COMPETIDORES; i++) {
            competidores objCompetidores = GuardaCompetidores[i];
            if (GuardaCompetidores[i].getEquipo().contains("Rápidos y Furiosos")) {
                tiempo += objCompetidores.getTiempoMangos() + objCompetidores.getTiempoHato()
                        + objCompetidores.getTiempoChuchecas() + objCompetidores.getTiempoGanaderos()
                        + objCompetidores.getTiempoPampa();

            }

        }
        return tiempo;
    }

    public String imprime() {
        String hileraM = "";
        String hileraH = "";
        String hileraC = "";
        String hileraG = "";
        String hileraP = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < COMPETIDORES; i++) {
            objCompetidores = etapas[1][i];
            hileraM += objCompetidores.infoCompeticionMangos();
            hileraH += objCompetidores.infoCompeticionHato();
            hileraC += objCompetidores.infoCompeticionChuchecas();
            hileraG += objCompetidores.infoCompeticionGanaderos();
            hileraP += objCompetidores.infoCompeticionPampa();
        }

        return "Mangos\n" + hileraM + "\nHato\n" + hileraH + "\nChuchecas\n" + hileraC
                + "\nGanaderos\n" + hileraG + "\nPampa\n" + hileraP;
    }

    public void Ordenar() {
        int tamanno = 1;
        competidores tiempoCompetidores = new competidores();
        for (int i = 0; i < COMPETIDORES; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COMPETIDORES - 1; j++) {

                if (etapas[tamanno][j].getTiempoMangos() > etapas[tamanno][j + 1].getTiempoMangos()) {
                    tiempoCompetidores = etapas[tamanno][j + 1];
                    etapas[tamanno][j + 1] = etapas[tamanno][j];
                    etapas[tamanno][j] = tiempoCompetidores;
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

2.Tengo competidores

```
public class competidores {

       
    private int cedula;
    private int edad;
    private String categoria;
    private String equipo;

    private int tiempoMangos;
    private int tiempoHato;
    private int tiempoChuchecas;
    private int tiempoGanaderos;
    private int tiempoPampa;
    private int TiempoAcumulado;

    public competidores() {
    }

    public int getCedula() {
        return cedula;
    }

    public void setCedula(int cedula) {
        this.cedula = cedula;
    }

    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public String getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }

    public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }

    public String getEquipo() {
        return equipo;
    }

    public void setEquipo(String equipo) {
        this.equipo = equipo;
    }

    public int getTiempoMangos() {
        return tiempoMangos;
    }

    public void setTiempoMangos(int tiempoMangos) {
        this.tiempoMangos = tiempoMangos;
    }

    public int getTiempoHato() {
        return tiempoHato;
    }

    public void setTiempoHato(int tiempoHato) {
        this.tiempoHato = tiempoHato;
    }

    public int getTiempoChuchecas() {
        return tiempoChuchecas;
    }

    public void setTiempoChuchecas(int tiempoChuchecas) {
        this.tiempoChuchecas = tiempoChuchecas;
    }

    public int getTiempoGanaderos() {
        return tiempoGanaderos;
    }

    public void setTiempoGanaderos(int tiempoGanaderos) {
        this.tiempoGanaderos = tiempoGanaderos;
    }

    public int getTiempoPampa() {
        return tiempoPampa;
    }

    public void setTiempoPampa(int tiempoPampa) {
        this.tiempoPampa = tiempoPampa;
    }

    public int getTiempoAcumulado() {
        return TiempoAcumulado;
    }

    public void setTiempoAcumulado(int TiempoAcumulado) {
        this.TiempoAcumulado = TiempoAcumulado;
    }

    
    
        public String infoCompetidores() {
         
        
        String hilera = this.getCedula() + "-" + this.getEdad() + "-" + this.getCategoria() + "-" + this.getEquipo() + "\n";
       
        return hilera;

    }

    public String infoCompeticionMangos() {
        String hilera;
        hilera = this.getCedula() + "-" + this.getEdad() + "-" + this.getCategoria() + "-" + this.getEquipo()+ "-"  + this.getTiempoMangos() + "\n";
        return hilera;

    }

    public String infoCompeticionHato() {
        String hilera;
        hilera = this.getCedula() + "-" +  this.getEdad() + "-" + this.getCategoria() + "-" + this.getEquipo()+ "-"  + this.getTiempoHato() + "\n";
        return hilera;

    }

    public String infoCompeticionChuchecas() {
        String hilera;
        hilera = this.getCedula() + "-" +this.getEdad() + "-" + this.getCategoria() + "-" + this.getEquipo()+ "-"  + this.getTiempoChuchecas() + "\n";
        return hilera;

    }

    public String infoCompeticionGanaderos() {
        String hilera;
        hilera = this.getCedula() + "-" +  this.getEdad() + "-" + this.getCategoria() + "-" + this.getEquipo()+ "-"  + this.getTiempoGanaderos() + "\n";
        return hilera;

    }

    public String infoCompeticionPampa() {
        String hilera;
        hilera = this.getCedula() + "-" +  this.getEdad() + "-" + this.getCategoria() + "-" + this.getEquipo()+ "-"  + this.getTiempoPampa() + "\n";
        return hilera;

    }

    public String infoCompeticionAcumulado() {
        String hilera;
        hilera =this.getCedula() + "-"  + this.getEdad() + "-" + this.getCategoria() + "-" + this.getEquipo()+ "-"  + this.getTiempoAcumulado() + "\n";
        return hilera;

    }

}
```

3.Tengo 5 competencias, en donde todos los competidores deben de competir para salir un ganador

```
public class CincoCompetencias {
    private String Mangos;
    private String Hato;
    private String Chuchecas;
    private String Ganaderos;
    private String Pampa;
    private int vueltasMangos;
    private int vueltasHato;
    private int vueltasChuchecas;
    private int vueltasGanaderos;
    private int vueltasPampa;

    

    public String getMangos() {
        return Mangos;
    }

    public void setMangos(String Mangos) {
        this.Mangos = Mangos;
    }

    public String getHato() {
        return Hato;
    }

    public void setHato(String Hato) {
        this.Hato = Hato;
    }

    public String getChuchecas() {
        return Chuchecas;
    }

    public void setChuchecas(String Chuchecas) {
        this.Chuchecas = Chuchecas;
    }

    public String getGanaderos() {
        return Ganaderos;
    }

    public void setGanaderos(String Ganaderos) {
        this.Ganaderos = Ganaderos;
    }

    public String getPampa() {
        return Pampa;
    }

    public void setPampa(String Pampa) {
        this.Pampa = Pampa;
    }

    public int getVueltasMangos() {
        return vueltasMangos;
    }

    public void setVueltasMangos(int vueltasMangos) {
        this.vueltasMangos = vueltasMangos;
    }

    public int getVueltasHato() {
        return vueltasHato;
    }

    public void setVueltasHato(int vueltasHato) {
        this.vueltasHato = vueltasHato;
    }

    public int getVueltasChuchecas() {
        return vueltasChuchecas;
    }

    public void setVueltasChuchecas(int vueltasChuchecas) {
        this.vueltasChuchecas = vueltasChuchecas;
    }

    public int getVueltasGanaderos() {
        return vueltasGanaderos;
    }

    public void setVueltasGanaderos(int vueltasGanaderos) {
        this.vueltasGanaderos = vueltasGanaderos;
    }

    public int getVueltasPampa() {
        return vueltasPampa;
    }

    public void setVueltasPampa(int vueltasPampa) {
        this.vueltasPampa = vueltasPampa;
    } 
    
}
```

4.Éstos son ejemplo de salidas.

```
             Ganaderos 
279-22-Juvenil-Velocidad Total-59842

361-51-Veterano-Prudencia Total-57375

338-41-Adulto Mayor- Prudencia-43261

489-37-Adulto Mayor- Prudencia-36410

244-64-Oro-Prudencia Total-49057

352-36-Adulto Mayor- Prudencia-37919

212-78-Oro-Prudencia Total-42080

135-71-Oro-Prudencia Total-42899

209-25-Juvenil-Velocidad Total-43595

243-37-Adulto Mayor- Prudencia-36902
```

5.No logro ordenar estas salidas por el último campo(es decir ordenar por tiempo), traté de colocar el método ordenar dentro de las competencias pero no logré que se ordeneran por el tiempo.

6.Tampoco logro mostrar el ganador que sería el de menor tiempo 1er lugar, 2do lugar y 3er lugar(tiempo del primero - tiempo del segundo...)

Comment: Hola!, tú método ordenar esta estupendo, no te funciona, por que lo guardas en arreglos distintos, me explico, tienes un arreglo para cada competición, y solo llamas a ordenar, pero no le pasas el arreglo para que ordene, el lo único que hace es ordenar el arreglo, pero al no haber retorno, desaparece lo que hizo una vez termina el método.

Comment: @HAROLDRUEDAANTOLINEZ Gracias por responder mi inquietud. Ahora, he tratado de guardar los datos en un mismo arreglo y no logro acomodar el orden de la salida. ¿Me ayudas por favor a darme un ejemplo de como hacer la ordenación? Un saludo

Comment: Hey Tudor, recuerda que debes mandar el arreglo como un parámetro al método ordenar y en el método ordenar retornar el arreglo, ya que al salir de ahí podría dar problema, ahora te adjunto un ejemplo 

Comment: De acuerdo @HAROLDRUEDAANTOLINEZ voy a revisarlo de nuevo.